# bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary> install BigARTM

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos

I trying to install BigARTM according to this [tutorial](http://bigartm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/linux_basic.html) on Centos 7. 
But I am getting this error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_chrono-mt
/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_timer-mt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libpthread.a(libpthread.o): In function 'sem_open':
(.text+0x6823): warning: the use of 'mktemp' is dangerous, better use 'mkstemp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: [bin/bigartm] Error 1
make[1]:  [src/bigartm/CMakeFiles/bigartm.dir/all] Error 2
make:  [all] Error 2
```

I installed the `'Development Tools'` using `yum`, and I found the libraries in `/usr/lib64`

```
rpm -ql boost-devel | grep '_program-\|_date_time-\|_thread-\|_filesystem-\|_iostreams-\|_system-\|_chrono-\|_timer-' 
/usr/lib64/libboost_chrono-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_iostreams-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_timer-mt.so
```

I tried three ways:

1. To create a link (using `ln`) from `/usr/lib64/libboost_<name>-mt.so` to `/usr/lib64/lboost_<name>-mt.so` and to add the `/usr/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
2. To create a link from `/usr/lib64/libboost_<name>-mt.so` to 
   `/usr/lib/lboost_<name>-mt.so`.
3. To add `LIBS  = -L /usr/lib64` to the MakeFile.

For example:

```
[oshri@analytics build]$ ls -l /usr/lib/\*program\*
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root 37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib/lboost_program_options-mt -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root 37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib/lboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
[oshri@analytics build]$ ls -l /usr/lib64/\*program\*
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root     37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib64/lboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx 4 root root     37 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 468952 Nov  5 20:58 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.53.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 Jan 19 17:38 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 468944 Nov  5 20:58 /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
[oshri@analytics build]$ printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/oshri/PycharmProjects/EuroSalesOptimization/runtime/:/usr/lib64/
```

Comment: You should not rename the library files, they have a name like "libXXXX", and compilers-linkers search for them when instructed to use "-lXXXX".

Instead, you should have "libXXXX.a" (note the `.a`) somewhere, and perhaps use ldconfig(8) or /etc/ld.so.conf to setup paths. Probably you must install the "*-devel" package version of the libraries.

Comment: I installed the boost-devel but without success. `sudo yum install boost-devel ` , `Package boost-devel-1.59.0-1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` any ides ?

Comment: I also ran this commend and found nothing `sudo find / -name libboost_thread-mt.a`

Comment: List the files in the package boost-devel-xxxxx: perhaps it can give you some idea. I really don't know anything more.

Comment: List the files in the package boost-devel-xxxxx: perhaps it can give you some idea. I really don't know anything more.

Comment: How can I "List the files"?

Comment: I think CentOS uses packages in RPM format. Google about it ("How can I list files in a RPM") or use a graphical package manager...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133753/discussion-between-oshribr-and-linuxfan).